# jQuery Bounce Effect on click no jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, bounce

I cannot find a solution to an animation to make a div bounce, using just jQuery animations. Something like does not work:

```
$("#bounce").click(function() {
    $(this).effect("bounce", {
        times: 3
    }, 300);
});.​
```

I would prefer not to use jQuery UI or any external plugin, such as the easing one. A wobble effect would be just as good in my case, so either will do.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jackdent/RaG9x/2/), any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: I would still suggest just using jQueryUI. I also hesitated using jQueryUI but as you can select which components of it you want to include in your download you can just select bounce and nothing else so the js + css files will be pretty small ~ 15kb

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could simply chain together some `animate` calls on the element like so:

```
$("#bounce").click(function() {
    doBounce($(this), 3, '10px', 300);   
});


function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element.animate({marginTop: '-='+distance}, speed)
            .animate({marginTop: '+='+distance}, speed);
    }        
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Willyham/AY5aL/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to save the fiddle. Check again now.

Comment: for those of you who can't get this to work, make sure there's no CSS transition property applied to the element you're trying to bounce. it may interfere because it's CSS properties we're manipulating here.

Comment: How can we stop the bouncing of this function by a button?

Answer (score 4):

Use this function for damped bounces. Be sure to give the bouncing element a unique class if using the code without changes.

```js
var getAttention = function(elementClass,initialDistance, times, damping) {
  for(var i=1; i<=times; i++){
      var an = Math.pow(-1,i)*initialDistance/(i*damping);
      $('.'+elementClass).animate({'top':an},100);
  }
  $('.'+elementClass).animate({'top':0},100);
}

$( "#bounce").click(function() {
 getAttention("bounce", 50, 10, 1.2);
});
```

```css
#bounce {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:#f00;
    margin-top:50px;
    position:relative;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bounce" class="bounce"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a vertical bounce you can try something like this:

```
function bounce(element, distance, speed){
 var bounce_margin_top = $(element).css("margin-top")
 $(element).css("margin-top", "-="+distance)

 $(element).show().fadeIn(200).animate({
    "margin-top": bounce_margin_top
 }, {
     duration: speed,
     easing:   "easeOutBounce"
 })
}
```

Comment: `easeOutBounce` requires jQuery Ui.

Comment: and in jQuery Ui you can just use shake

Answer (score 1):

I use this simple plugin, [jQuery-Shake](https://github.com/ninty9notout/jquery-shake), to shake **or bounce** an element without jQuery-UI.

```
$('#elementToBounce').shake({direction: up, distance:10, speed: 75, times: 3})
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek7swb6y/3/

Comment: Excellent! Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use jQuery animate. For your specific question, it could look like this:

The HTML:

```
<div id="bounce"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
#bounce {
height:50px;
width:50px;
background:#333;
margin-top:50px;
position:relative;
}
```

And finally, the jQuery:

```
$( "#bounce" ).click(function() {
for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
$(this).animate({top: 30},"slow");
$(this).animate({top: 0},"slow");
     }
});
```

And here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xz29fet/1/

Answer (score 0):

Combining different answers, this is what worked for me after click

```js
let el = $('.bounce-me');
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  el.animate({ 'margin-top': 15 }, 'fast').animate(
    { 'margin-top': -15 },
    'fast'
  );
}
el.animate({ 'margin-top': 0 }, 'fast');
```