# JQuery Bouncing Effect

Tags: jquery, html

Got a few lines of coder here im trying to figure out why it isnt working. Its a simple .effect in jquery that is triggered in a click of a button.

```
$(document).on('click','#sub', function(){
    $('.circle').effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 300 );
});
```

The error im faced with is Uncaught `TypeError: $(...).effect` is not a function in console. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `effect()` method isn't part of jQuery core, but jQuery UI... So include jQuery UI too. That's said, you could animate it using CSS instead

Comment: What's the version of jQuery you are using and does that version have an api called effect()?

Comment: @A.Wolff sorry im quite new to jquery what do you mean i need to include the jquery ui too?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> is what i linked to

Comment: [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) != jQuery core. Include jQuery UI after jQuery

Comment: went to go download and go an error :/

Comment: @factordog So you are doing something wrong...  Without describing what you are doing nor error you get, how do you expect someone else to help???

Comment: Also, `.effect()` is jQueryUI, https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ this ones are jQuery

Comment: @miguelmpnit already is wrapped in $(document).ready im just trying to get that part of the code working. A. Wolff I went to download the Jquery UI and it said bad connection to their server, so will have to wait till I can actually download the file to use it

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363671/jquery-bounce-effect-on-click-no-jquery-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from the question and the discussing below, its clear that your are missing Jquery UI file. Import the  [Jquery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js)

I Have created fiddle for your question for Help.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tg0opwqr/)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js">
```

-Help :)

Comment: Okay great, would I link that after my <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script> which holds that code?

Comment: nevermind its working ^^ had to remove some old links to ajax library that was there! thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check CSS the version, I made this Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g45v2f9f/6/

With this you only need normal jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#sub', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('effect');
  })
});
```

The effect class has the transition and it is added when you click the circle